# How to set parameter local date in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, restlet

I am creating program "Ad catalog" that executes CRUD operations. I need to run method save(Ad ad), Ad includes parameter local date. I put JSON code through Restlet to get a result but it gives me error 500 (wrong local date). How do I put local date to be correct?

I tried to write it like "date": "2012-03-19T07:22Z", "date": "2019-09-19", "date": 2019-09-19 and don't put it at all but it didn't work.

```
@Entity
public class Ad {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ad_id")
private int id;
private String name;
private LocalDate date;
private String text;
@Column(name = "price", precision = 10, scale = 2)
private BigDecimal price;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "author_fk_id")
private Author author;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_fk_id")
private Category category;
.....
}



@RestController
@RequestMapping("ad")
public class AdController {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("adServiceImpl")
private AdService<Ad> adService;

@PostMapping("/save")
public void save(@RequestBody Ad ad) {
     adService.save(ad);
}
}


 JSON
{
"id": 0,
"name": "house for sale",
"text": "selling a house in barry ave, 5 ears old",
"date": 2019-09-20,
"price": 250.00,
"author": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Liza",
    "phone": {
        "id": 0,
        "number": "3121001111"
    },
    "address": {
        "id": 0,
        "country": "RUSSIA",
        "city": "MOSCOW"
    },
    "email": {
        "id": 0,
        "email": "liza@mail.ru"
    }
},
"category": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "houses"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **private LocalDate date;** use the **java.sql.date** type and pass the date in json like this **"date": 2019-09-20,**

it will work and if you want to convert that date formate to other local date formate use the **SimpleDateFormat** and parse it.